# Compute $\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{2x - x^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I couldn't find the appropriate transformation for this integral. Can someone help me?

> $$\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{2x - x^2}\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Can you complete the square of the exponent? Also the [*Gaussian integral*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) might help you.

Comment: @SangchulLee Then, it is $\frac{e \sqrt{\Pi}}{2}$.

Comment: Glad you figured out by yourself :)

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- $\mathrm{e} \cdot \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}} = 1$.
- $-1+2x-x^2 = -(x-1)^2$
- Then this is a shifted [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), as observed in comments by Sangchul Lee.

Answer (score 0):

Start by completing the square in the exponent:

\begin{align}
-x^2+2x&=-(x^2-2x) \\
&=-(x^2-2x+1-1) \\
&=-(x-1)^2+1
\end{align}
Your integral is then equal to
\begin{align}
\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-(x-1)^2+1}\,dx&=e\int_1^{+\infty} e^{-(x-1)^2}\,dx \\
&=e\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx \\
&=\boxed{\frac{e\sqrt{\pi}}{2}}
\end{align}